# Which one is the correct notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, notation

I know this notation is correct:

$a_1,a_2, a_3,\cdots,a_n=\left\{a_k\right\}_{k=1}^n$

Now, we have a function $f(n)$.

I want to write this sequence in correct notation:

$\left\{ f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots ,f(n)\right\}$

I have two notations.  Which one is correct?

> $\bigcup_{k=1}^nf(k)=\left\{ f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots , f(n)\right\}$
>
> $\left\{f(k)\right\}_{k=1}^n=\left\{ f(1),f(2),f(3),\cdots, f(n)\right\}$

Thank you.

Comment: Second one is correct, because the first one look like $$f(1) \cup f(2) \cup \cdots \cup f(n)$$

Comment: Also used is $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ with $I=\{1,\ldots ,n\}$.

Comment: The first one is incorrect; you should change its left-hand side to $\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{f(k)\}$.

Comment: @J.G. $\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{f(k)\}=\left\{f(1),\cdots,f(n)\right\}$ is correct. Do I understand correct?

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR is it possible can you explain me what is the exact meaning of this notation $\bigcup_{k=1}^n \cdots$

Comment: @Learner You've understood me correctly. For sets $S_k$, $\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k$ is the union of the sets $S_k$ with $1\le k\le n$, i.e. $\bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k=\{x|\exists k(1\le k\le n\land x\in S_k)\}$.

Comment: If you write $$\bigcup_{k=1}^n \{f(k)\}$$, then this union is somewhat meaningfull. But you wrote $$\bigcup_{k=1}^n f(k)$$  which is meaningless unless $f(k)$ is a **set**. But here $f(k)$ is a **number**

Comment: @J.G.  Thank you so much.I learned that it was possible to make correct notation with a bracket.We deduce, $\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{f(k)\}=\left\{{f(k)}\right\}_{k=1}^n$ is correct. Both notation are correct.am I right?

Comment: @Learner We'd usually write the right-hand side as $\{f(k)|1\le k\le n\}$ or, if we construe a finite sequence as a set (which is awkward if $f$'s values ever repeat), $(f(k))_{k=1}^n$ or $(f(k))_{1\le k\le n}$.

Comment: @J.G. thank you for teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

$$\left\{a_k\right\}_{k=1}^n,$$ $a_k$ can be anything. For instance $f(k)$.

But
$$\bigcup$$ is a set operator, so that its arguments must be sets, which the $f(k)$ are probably not. Even if you used $\{f(k)\}$, you would still obtain a set instead of a sequence (a set is unordered).

Comment: (+), I am stuck because $k$ is not index for $f(k)$.

Comment: @Learner: and ?

Comment: And I accepted your answer ✓

Comment: @Learner  :-) :-)